# Как разместить текст на фото?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1. Как лучше делать такие элементы? делать картинку absolute или текст absolute?
2. если все же картинку, так как разместить текст если он не по центру, правее?

Answer (score 0):

В целом зависит от того, какой должен быть размером родительский блок.
Как по мне проще использовать такой вариант:

```css
.img-text {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.img-text img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.img-text div {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.75);
  padding: .15em .25em;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: absolute;
  right: 25%;
  bottom: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-text">
  <img src="//i.imgur.com/8G06qBx.png">
  <div>Мороз и солнце</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Либо и картинке и тексту absolute, либо к блоку с текстом добавить background-image.

Comment: но если я дам тексту например left 500px при сужении экрана текст может сломатся

Comment: Насчёт текста можно поставить `left: 50%` и `transform: translateX(-50%)`, а картинка может поломаться, да.

Comment: Или поставить картинке `width: 100%` - тоже вариант, соответственно только тексту `absolute`.